# how to call the sudo command in linux using Puppet

Tags: puppet

Using the below script to call sudo command in redhat linux with the puppet version 3.7.

```
Exec {

  cwd => "/home/dev02",
  command => "sudo -su dev01",
  path => "/usr/bin/",
  logoutput => "on_failure",
}
```

I am not getting any errors, but after executing this script,
when i checked to see my user with "whoami", still am seeing as dev02
instead of dev01.

Can someone help me on this.?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

This command will not do what you expect because all `exec` resource commands are executed in a spawned process. If you want to execute a command as another user, then the [`exec` resource has a `user` parameter](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/type.html#exec-attribute-user).

For example:

```
exec { 'Touch some file':
  cwd       => '/home/dev02',
  command   => 'touch some_file',
  path      => '/usr/bin/',
  logoutput => 'on_failure',
  user      => 'dev01'
}
```

Comment: And even *that* will not magically transpose your interactive shell to run with a different UID. The only way to do this by script is making it a **shell** script and **source**-ing that shell script (i.e., run the commands *in your current shell*). Anything else cannot affect your running process.